# Martingale $c^{W_t}$ where $W$ is Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales

I have the process $c^{W_{t}}$ where $c$ is a constant and $W$ is Brownian motion. I would like to check if  $\mathbb E[c^{W_{t+1}}|F_t]=c^{W_t}$. Dividing the right site yield $\mathbb E[c^{W_{t+1}-W_{t}}|F_t]=c^{0}=1$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $c$ is such that $\mathbb{E}[c^{W_{t+1}} \mid F_t] = c^{W_t}$ then it will also be true that $E[c^{W_{t+1}-W_t} \mid F_t] = 1$.  This is simply the well-known property of conditional expectation that if $Y$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{G}$, then $Y E[X \mid \mathcal{G}] = E[XY \mid \mathcal{G}]$.

If I am not mistaken, you will find that the only positive $c$ for which this statement holds is $c=1$.

Comment: Whs is that not true for $c$ not equal to $1$?

Comment: @Alkibiades: If we take the (unconditional) expectation of both sides of $E[c^{W_{t+1}-W_t} \mid F_t] = 1$ we get $E[c^{W_{t+1} - W_t}] = 1$.  Now $W_{t+1} - W_t$ is a standard normal random variable (mean 0 and variance 1), and if you look up (or compute) the moment generating function of a standard normal random variable $N$, you see $E[e^{tN}] = e^{t^2/2}$.  Taking $t = \ln c$ we have $E[c^N] = e^{(\ln c)^2/2}$.  Setting that equal to $1$ you find it is only satisfied when $\ln c = 0$, i.e. $c=1$.